# Create and index from returns PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have the following dataframe where the first two columns are monthly returns (you have to multiply by 100 to get it in %)

```
                in_scenario_USA  out_scenario_USA  USA
month year                                        
6     1960         0.000000          0.019524  0.0
7     1960         0.000000         -0.024772  0.0
8     1960         0.000000          0.026121  0.0
9     1960         0.000000         -0.060393  0.0
10    1960         0.000000         -0.002429  0.0
11    1960         0.000000          0.040270  0.0
12    1960         0.000000          0.046273  0.0
1     1961         0.000000          0.063156  0.0
2     1961         0.026870          0.000000  1.0
3     1961         0.025536          0.000000  1.0
                     ...               ...  ...
4     2017         0.000000          0.009091  0.0
5     2017         0.000000          0.011576  0.0
6     2017         0.000000          0.004814  0.0
7     2017         0.019349          0.000000  1.0
8     2017         0.000546          0.000000  1.0
```

I wish to create two indices that would start at 1 for the first value non NaN for the USA column and then basically:
- The first index will be based on the return of the first column
- The second index will be based on the returns of the second column

for example the first one would be like that

```
                in_scenario_USA  first index 
month year                                        
6     1960         0.000000          1
7     1960         0.000000          1  
8     1960         0.000000          1
9     1960         0.000000          1
10    1960         0.000000          1
11    1960         0.000000          1
12    1960         0.000000          1
1     1961         0.000000          1
2     1961         0.026870          1.026870
3     1961         0.025536          1.053092
4     1961         0.003843          1.057139
5     1961         0.000000          1.057139
6     1961         0.000000          1.057139
```

I am kind of struggling about the way to iterate that in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this i think:

```
df['First index'] = df.in_scenario_USA.cumsum().add(1)
```

Comment: Thanks but I believe that sums numbers while I need to multiply the previous value by (1 + the number in scenario)

Comment: so you need something like this? `df['First index'] = df.in_scenario_USA.shift() * (1+df.in_scenario_USA)`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. As I understand I need to combine an element wise multiplication with a row iteration. I tried within a for loop with: (`df_merged[col + ' index_in'].iloc[i] = np.multiply(df_merged[col + ' index_in'].iloc[i-1], df_merged['in_scenario_' + col].iloc[i])`) but it still doesn't work.