# Python create index from returns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of portfolio returns:

```
date          Portfolio %
30/11/2001     4.8
31/12/2001    -0.7
31/01/2002     1.3
28/02/2002    -1.4
29/03/2002     3.3
```

I need to create an index of returns, but to do this i need to have a starting figure of 1.0 and the formula references the previous row. The output should look like this:

```
date          Portfolio %   Index
               1.0          NaN
30/11/2001     4.8          1.048          
31/12/2001    -0.7          1.040
31/01/2002     1.3          1.054
28/02/2002    -1.4          1.039
29/03/2002     3.3          1.073
```

As an example the formula for the second result is:
`1.048*(1+-0.7/100)`
I've tried the following code, but it doesn't get the required result.

```
portfolio['Index'] = portfolio['Portfolio %'] / portfolio['Portfolio %'].iloc[0]
```

The issues i have:

- I can't get the starting variable
- I can't get the formula to reference the previous row.

I believe it is the same issue as this post: [Create and index from returns PANDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934338/create-and-index-from-returns-pandas). However, it was never answered fully.

Comment: Do you really want first row to be `1.0 NaN`, as you haven't specified any index for that row..

Comment: As long as the result (Index ) for 30/11/2001 = 1.048, i don't really mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html), [`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) along with [`Series.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) :

```
df['Index'] = df['Portfolio %'].div(100).add(1).cumprod()
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

         date  Portfolio %     Index
0  30/11/2001          4.8  1.048000
1  31/12/2001         -0.7  1.040664
2  31/01/2002          1.3  1.054193
3  28/02/2002         -1.4  1.039434
4  29/03/2002          3.3  1.073735
```